# How do I write a Scala unit test to verify that a function is called with some particular function as a parameter?

Tags: function, scala, unit-testing, verify

I have a class:

```
class SomeDao {
  this: support =>

  def get(id:Long): Option[SomeDto] = {
     support.sprocCall(SomeDto.fromResultSet, SomeDao.getSproc, id)
  }  
}
```

SomeDto.fromResultSet is actually a Function1 [WrapperResultSet, SomeDto].

Is it possible to verify that support.sprocCall has been called with the correct function as the first parameter?

Comment: Mockito can do this.

Comment: [Similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11802801/using-mockito-how-do-i-verify-a-method-was-a-called-with-a-certain-argument?rq=1)

Comment: @Daenyth, we were playing with mockitosugar and the best we could do was figure out how to prove that the parameter SomeDto.fromResultSet was called with a Function1 (instead of just anyObject).

Comment: @Michael Kendra, thanks for the response but there is a significant difference.  In this instance, we want to verify that the first argument is a particular function and not just a particular value.

Answer (score 1):

This question has two parts. First, you need to test what was the argument to a method invocation inside your class. Second, you want to do some form of function equality.

As mentioned in the comments, to solve the first problem you can use `Mockito`. See the example below on how to do that using `ArgumentCaptor`.

Now, the second part is more complex. See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12725257/how-to-compare-scala-function-values-for-equality) about function equality. In the code example below, I forced the functions `func1` and `func2` to be instantiated and stored them into `val func_a` and `val func_b` respectively. I then used the two val throughout my test code. If doing something similar is not possible during your test, then I am afraid there is NO good way of achieving what you need.

To better show the problem of function equality in Scala, I added the last two lines in the example.

```scala
import org.mockito.ArgumentCaptor
import org.mockito.Matchers._
import org.mockito.Mockito._

object ToyExample extends App {
  // A toy class
  class TargetClass {
    def add(str: String, func: String => Long, j: Long): Long = func(str) + j
  }

  // These are the two functions we can use 
  def func1(g: String): Long = g.toLong
  def func2(g: String): Long = g.toLong * 2

  // Here is an example of using the TargetClass 
  val actualInstance = new TargetClass
  println( actualInstance.add("12", ToyExample.func1, 2) ) // Prints 14

  // Here is with the mock
  val mockedSomeDao = mock(classOf[TargetClass])

  val func_a = func1 _
  val func_b = func2 _

  // ... use the mocked object to do what you want
  mockedSomeDao.add("12", func_a,  2)

  // Now verify that the argument is the right one
  val argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(classOf[(String) => Long])

  verify(mockedSomeDao, atLeastOnce()).add(anyString(), argument.capture(), anyLong())

  if( argument.getValue eq func_a ) {
    println("Func 1") // This one gets called
  } else if (argument.getValue eq func_b) {
    println("Func 2")
  }

  println( func_a eq func_a) // Prints "true"
  println( func1 _ eq func1 _) // Prints "false"!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're treading very close to the problem of determining if two functions are equal. That particular problem has been covered many times on SO, such as [How to compare Scala function values for equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12725257/how-to-compare-scala-function-values-for-equality)
I believe your question is just a less general form of that question.  If so, the answer is that you can't do it for good reasons founded in theory.