# Writing unit-test to check logging in exception

Tags: java, unit-testing, exception, mockito

I want to write unit-test to check work of log.error function when exception is catched.
I have this class:

```
class SalesMasterModelDateSequenceWrapper {

public static List<EMDate> getDatesClass(IAnalysisExpressionContext context, IContract contract, EMDate analysisDate, IExpressionLogger log, Lookup lookup) {

    try {

        StringBuilder scenarioName = new StringBuilder();
        scenarioName.append(contract.getStringFDA(lookup.getServerFDA("NewContractsForecastName").toLowerCase()));
        if (scenarioName.toString().length()==0) return new ArrayList<>();
        scenarioName.append("_").append(analysisDate.year()).append(analysisDate.month()).append(analysisDate.day());
        if (!context.getScenarioName().contains(scenarioName.toString())){
            return Arrays.asList(contract.getValueDate());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("SalesMasterModelDateSequence: ").append(e.getMessage()).append("\n");
        for (StackTraceElement stackTraceElement : e.getStackTrace())
        {
            sb.append(stackTraceElement.toString()).append("\n");
        }
        log.error(sb.toString());
    }
    return new ArrayList<>();

}
```

I want to verify that I'll take the result of log.error(sb.toString()). Can somebody help with this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check if this helps: [how-to-do-a-junit-assert-on-a-message-in-a-logger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827677/how-to-do-a-junit-assert-on-a-message-in-a-logger)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unse a *mocking framework* to create a mock of `IExpressionLogger` and in your test verify that its `error()` method has been called with the expected parameter:

```
@Rule 
public MockitoRule mockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule(); 
@Mock
private IExpressionLogger expressionLogger;
@Mock
private Lookup lookup;
@Test
public void exceptionMessageLoggedAsError() {
 doThrow(new RuntimeException("UnitTest").when(lookup).getServerFDA(anyString());

  new SalesMasterModelDateSequenceWrapper(/* other parameters */,expressionLogger, lookup).getDatesClass(/* parameters */);

  verify(expressionLogger).error("the expected message containing substring 'UnitTest' from Exception");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be pretty straight forward, as you **directly** provide the object on which `error()` is called to the method under test.

Thus: simply *mock* that object, for example using Mockito.

And then you use the *verify* functionality of Mockito to ensure that you see that call to `log.error()` with the expected string value.

You can find many examples how to do that; for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11802801/using-mockito-how-do-i-verify-a-method-was-a-called-with-a-certain-argument).

Given your specific example, you could even write your own stub implementation of that logging interface; and have that code simply remember any strings given to it. So that you can afterwards simply ask the stub to return that string passed into it.